# Personal pronoun in a dependent sentence

Tags: grammar

> Das Mädchen musste sich täglich auf die grosse Strasse bei einem Brunnen setzen und musste so viel spinnen, dass ihm das Blut aus den Fingern sprang.

What does exactly *ihm* mean here? I can completely understand the sentence, but that *ihm* seems to be redundant for me.

Comment: Which other languages do you speak?

Comment: Russian is my native one.

Comment: It's comparable to saying *iemu 10 liet* instead of *on imeet 10 liat*.

Comment: I don't think that it's grammatically redundant. Of course, if you drop the pronoun you still would understand this sentence, because there's no possible ambiguity whatsoever; but from a grammar perspective, it's necessary.

Comment: Is it any reference where I can learn why is it grammatically necessary?

Comment: It means that something happened **to someone**. Often the pronoun is not necessary, because it's clear from context to whom something happened, but sometimes that is not the case: Das Blut sprang aus den Fingern. (=Blood spilled from the fingers.) Das Blut sprang **ihr** aus den Fingern. (**To her it happened that** blood spilled from the fingers.)

Comment: @Em1 ... you're wrong. "Das Blut sprang aus den Fingern" is a grammatical sentence, so a Dative "experiencer" is NOT needed for grammar.

Comment: @Emanuel Sorry, I wasn't quite clear. I didn't mean to say that it would be incorrect without it. But it certainly has its grammatical function, and if you leave it out, you can lose some important information. Not in this sentence, though, because it's certainly unambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ihm** (personal pronoun, not possesive) means that it happened **to the girl**. Here's a similar example:

> Das Blut sprang aus den Fingern. *(Blood spilled from the fingers.)*
>   Das Blut sprang **ihr** aus den Fingern. *(**To her it happened that** blood spilled from the fingers.)*

Not using the personal pronoun in the original sentence, leaves it technically undefined whos blood is spilling, although context strongly suggests that it's the girl's blood.

Comparable with the Latin *Mihi nomen est* (To me the name is) instead of 
*Meus nomen est* (My name is).

---

Old answer (misread question, left for trivia):

*Ihm* refers to *das Mädchen*, which is grammatically neuter, while in fact a female. Likewise one would say:

> Das Mädchen, welches... *(neuter pronoun, correct)*
>   Das Mädchen, welche... *(feminine pronoun, wrong)*

But in your sentence, I think it's possible to use *ihr*, too:

> Das Mädchen musste sich täglich auf die grosse Strasse bei einem Brunnen setzen und musste so viel spinnen, dass ihr das Blut aus den Fingern sprang.

Mostly because *Mädchen* isn't perceived as a diminuitive* anymore, but rather as the standard term for "girl". Interestingly, the female version with *welche* sounds completely wrong.

<sup>*Magd *(=maid, female)* → Mägdchen *(diminuitive, always neuter)* → Mädchen</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The "ihm" emphasizes that it's the girl whose fingers the blood comes out of. Or put more generally, that it's the girl to whom something happened. 
It would be understandable without the Dative but having it there is a general German fashion

> Ich habe das Buch gelesen, das ich **mir** gekauft habe.
>   Der Dieb hat **mir** mein Handy geklaut.

The "mir" wouldn't really be needed in these sentences but they sound more idiomatic and alive with it in them.

Comment: (S)he could've bought the book for someone else.

Comment: @Grantwalzer... technically yes, but I am pretty sure that in combination with the first part of the sentence, most people would assume that I bought it for me, if the recipient were missing entirely. Also, if the person who gets it is someone other than the buyer that has a significantly higher informational value which is why it's very likely that the person  who gets it will be mentioned. That adds redundancy to "Mir" because if no person is mentioned,it's likely that there is none other than the buyer. Bottom line... theoretically you're right but that has little effect on language in use

Comment: compare also English that can get by without "for myself" just fine. The reason it's there in German is a matter of general style or preference, not content.

Comment: Agree with everything but the last sentence, since there's still a slight difference in meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The verb *springen* requires the dative case and, as *Mädchen* is neuter, the pronoun *ihm* is used.  Had the young lady been referred to as *Frau* then the pronoun *ihr* would have been appropriate.

Comment: It seems just wrong.

Comment: @VadimPushtaev: the answer is correct. *Mädchen* is neuter as has to be the pronoun replacing it (*ihm*). This is somewhat handled more liberal today, when it would also be possible to refer to *Mädchen* with a female pronoun but this would be gramatically wrong. The Grimms were very strict about this.

Comment: I mean it's not about _springen_ requires _Dativ_.

Comment: How does *springen* require dative case?